# Unable to hang up phone call

Tags: phone-app, htc-desire-z

I'm using a relatively new G2, and when dialing today, the call did not complete. It stayed in dialing forever. The hangup button did not work. I tried to force a connection failure with airplane mode, that did not work either.

Any ideas on what do in this situation? Ideally, I would like to know how to gather more data on the problem, so I can report it to T-Mobile and/or Google.

Comment: have you tried looking if anything is suspicious at logcat?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the Dialer froze.  Try holding the Home button, going into Task Manager, and killing the dialier process.

As Matt mentions in the comments,

> You can do the same thing from the home screen by pressing menu then going to settings > Applications > Manage Application then choose the "phone" or "dialer" app and click "stop"

Comment: If I hold onto the home screen, I get "Add to Home screen"... any other ways to do this?

Comment: Haha man, I must have been multitasking when I wrote that.  I meant Home *button*.

Comment: When I hold the home button, I get a Window-style "alt-tab" display, it says "Recent". Is this where I kill the process?

Comment: Hmm, maybe your phone doesn't have it.  My "Recent" list has a button at the bottom that says Task Manager.  Perhaps it's a 2.2 feature.  I don't think 2.2 has been officially released for the G2 (?) but have you considered a custom ROM?  It might even solve the dialer problem completely.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=512

Comment: I think its an OS issue, not a device issue, but on 1.6 Donut there's mos def no task manager in the recent apps shown when you hold down the home button.

Comment: You can do the same thing from the home screen by pressing menu then going to settings > Applications > Manage Application then choose the "phone" or "dialer" app and click "stop".

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ongoing issue, it is worth watching your logs to figure out what might be happening. I've got a G1 and every few months it chokes on something and I have to reboot it (which I do by holding down the power button until the phone powers off, or, when that fails, taking the battery out, counting to ten and replacing it.)